# Very strange - %i didn't work for integer, %d did?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, integer

It was very strange when I saw this on debugging my application.

```
int iTag = btnTemp.tag;    //btnTemp.tag = 1
NSString *strFriendID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",iTag];
```

gave me **strFriendID** as empty string.

```
int iTag = btnTemp.tag;       //btnTemp.tag = 1
NSString *strFriendID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iTag];
```

gave me **strFriendID** as **1**.

How can this happen?

Comment: That *is* strange, can you verify with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%d|%i]",iTag,iTag]` -- what is the result of that? (Note usage of both, the "working" first, and zomg-I-was-tricked guards.)

Comment: I checked it in my app.. It is working fine.. Both %d and %i giving me 1...

Comment: Exactly Karan. Don't know why.

Comment: I doubt there is an answer for that ! this is really strange !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know why you get this answer, but when i read your question i tried in my project but i get the value

```
UIButton *btnTemp = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
btnTemp.tag = 1;
int iTag = btnTemp.tag;    //btnTemp.tag = 1
NSString *strFriendID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",iTag];  
NSLog(@"Str %@", strFriendID);
NSString *strFriendID1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",iTag];  
NSLog(@"Str %@", strFriendID1);
```

Out Put

```
2012-03-26 10:32:02.899 Leaves[506:f803] Str 1
2012-03-26 10:32:02.901 Leaves[506:f803] Str 1
```

both gives me 1

Answer (score 1):

As per [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html):

```
 %d, %D and %i all represent Signed 32-bit integers.
```

So yeah it's weird that %i didn't work but it's not so weird that %d worked.

Perhaps btnTemp.tag was null at that point

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, you are just typing out what's in author's head.

Comment: Well I would comment but my rep isn't high enough :p